# Help with ID of this chip from a Bluetooth speaker - top marking AWF ANG (AWFANG)

Tags: identification

[image: photo of unknown IC on PCB]

I am trying to find out what this chip is or what it does.

It is from a Bluetooth speaker which is not charging the battery.  I have no idea if this is at fault, but would like to rule it out.

It only has pins on 3 sides, top and bottom has 5 each and left hand side has 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Silergy [SY6982EQDC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809191920_Silergy-Corp-SY6982EQDC_C108510.pdf) **High Efficiency, 2A, Two-Cell Boost Li-Ion Battery Charger**.

[image]

Comment: How do you found it?

Comment: @G36 Search with appropriate keywords in English and simplified Chinese.